# Laravel with SQL Server cannot use having with an alias

Tags: sql, sql-server, laravel, eloquent, geospatial

I'm trying to get get the stations located in a specified range (500 m) and I used this query:

```
        $query = Station::leftjoin('Area', 'Area.ID', 'Station.AreaID')->selectRaw("Station.StationID, Station.Name, Station.Name_AR, Area.AreaName, Station.Location.Lat as Lat, Station.Location.Long as Lng,
                         ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) *
                           cos( radians( Station.Location.Lat ) )
                           * cos( radians( Station.Location.Long ) - radians(?)
                           ) + sin( radians(?) ) *
                           sin( radians( Station.Location.Lat ) ) )
                         ) AS distance", [ $Lat, $Lon, $Lat ])
        ->having('distance', '<', 500)
        ->get();
```

After executing this query I get this exception:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL
>   Server]Invalid column name 'distance'. (42S22)

Comment: You can only use `having` if you have a `group by` in most databases, including SQL Server.

Comment: I got the same exception when I use GroupBy('distance')

Comment: . . You need to use a subquery or CTE define the value.

Comment: You need to repeat the distance calculation in the having clause. SQL Server does not support passing an alias to the having clause. And you will need to group by the other columns.